# Rust handling variable outside the scoped_threshhold

Tags: multithreading, rust, threadpool, ownership

from rust beginner.

I have some problems about ownership I think. What i wanna do is changing "ret" which is boolean
type variable inside the pool block. But when i ran the code and checked the ret, it changed well inside the pool block but outside the block, ret alway behave as true,,,
plz fix my headache...

```
let mut pool = Pool::new(max_worker);
let mut ret = true;
pool.scoped(|scoped| {
    for i in 0..somevalue{         
        scoped.execute( move || {
            let ret_ref = &mut ret;
            
            // Do Something

            if success {
                *ret_ref = false
            }   
        });
    }
});
if ret == true { /* Do Something */ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`scoped_threadpool::Pool::scoped(&mut self, <closure>)`](https://docs.rs/scoped_threadpool/0.1.9/scoped_threadpool/struct.Pool.html#method.scoped) returns a closure that impls [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) which means you can only call it once. You had it inside a `for` loop which is why the compiler kept giving you errors with confusing suggestions. Once you refactor the code to move the `for` outside the call to `scoped` then it compiles and works as expected:

```rust
use scoped_threadpool::Pool;

fn main() {
    let max_workers = 1;
    let somevalue = 1;

    let mut pool = Pool::new(max_workers);
    let mut ret = true;
    let ret_ref = &mut ret;

    for i in 0..somevalue {
        pool.scoped(|scoped| {
            scoped.execute(|| {
                // do something
                let success = true;

                if success {
                    *ret_ref = false
                }
            });
        });
    }

    if ret == true {
        println!("ret stayed true");
    } else {
        // prints this
        println!("ret was changed to false in the scoped thread");
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6cc3b17d5eb94a978c5f2ca3cf1218e0)